# Replace CSS background image with font awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How can I replace a background image url with a font awesome icon?

I have the following nav with:

```
<li class="active"><a href="anotherPAge" class="dispatch">Test</a></li>
```

The dispatch css:

```
nav ul li a.dispatch {background: url(../images/portal-sprite.png) no-repeat -160px 5px;}
```

portal-sprite.png is a file with images (icons). How can I replace it to include the font awesome user-check icon in the CSS background?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried applying the icon as `content` in a pseudo element? https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3Schools has a good example on z-index. You can use the z-index property to place the font awesome icon behind any other element. You need to place the icon in the html though instead of using `background` in CSS. The example also uses an image. Just replace the image with your icon and the heading and text with your list element. Hope that helps.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

HTML:

```
<h1>The z-index Property</h1>

<img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140">

<p>Because the image has a z-index of -1, it will be placed behind the heading.</p>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```